# Scrapy Splash with xpath not returning any results

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

The page I'm trying to scrape is
https://www.biggerpockets.com/forums/88/topics/895460-cap-rate-vs-interest-rate

The xpath in the developer console returns the text element which corresponds to the title of the post

[Developer Console xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOqux.png)

However, when running the scrapy, the same xpath doesn't work and the title returns 'None'

```
yield SplashRequest("https://www.biggerpockets.com/forums/88/topics/895460-cap-rate-vs-interest-rate", self.parse_post, args={'wait': 2})

def parse_post(self, response):
  title = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "simplified-forums__discussion")]//div[contains(@class, "simplified-forums__discussion__first-post")]//div[contains(@class, "simplified-forums__card__content")]//h1/text()').get()
  print(title)
```

```
2023-11-01 00:16:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.biggerpockets.com/forums/49/topics/276013-interest-rate>
None
```

When I access

http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www.biggerpockets.com/forums/88/topics/895460-cap-rate-vs-interest-rate

the page renders fine as well, not sure what exactly is wrong, because I am confident that the xpath is correct.

If I am missing anything, please help me out

Comment: Did you try adding the h1 tags class "simplified-forums__topic-content__title" ?

Comment: title = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "simplified-forums__discussion")]//div[contains(@class, "simplified-forums__discussion__first-post")]//div[contains(@class, "simplified-forums__card__content")]//h1[@class="simplified-forums__topic-content__title"]/text()').get()

Comment: Like I said, XPath is fine

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, your xpath seems to be wrong.

```
import scrapy

class biggerpockets(scrapy.Spider):
    name ='biggerpockets'
    start_urls = ['https://www.biggerpockets.com/forums/88/topics/895460-cap-rate-vs-interest-rate']
    
    def parse(self,response):

        title = response.xpath("//h1[@class='simplified-forums__topic-content__title']/text()").get()
        print("-------Extracted text-----------------")
        print(title)
        print("------------------------")
```

[image]

Comment: Try the XPath given by me, it works when I run it without Splash,